# PHP 5.43.4 /sapi/cli/php: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.48:

Tags: php, linux, compilation, plesk

`I'm trying to compile PHP 5.43.4 as an alternate PHP version on a Plesk 12 Centos 5.10 server (as shown in` `http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/118378`).
`After fulfilling all requisites ran the following configure:`

```
./configure '--with-libdir=lib64' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--prefix=/usr/local/php5434-cgi' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php5434-cgi/etc' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-fastcgi' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php5434-cgi' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php5434-cgi' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php5434-cgi' '--with-openssl' '--with-pspell' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos' '--with-unixODBC=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite3' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/php5434-cgi' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli' '--with-snmp' '--enable-soap' '--with-xsl' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--enable-pdo' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-pear=/usr/local/php5434-cgi/pear' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-intl' '--without-pdo-sqlite' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5434-cgi/php.d'

    After configure, ran make but I'm getting the following error:    Generating phar.php /usr/local/src/php5434/php-5.4.34/sapi/cli/php: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory      make: *** [ext/phar/phar.php] Error 127


    As ICU 48 was not installed, I proceeded to install it through a regular RPM install as YUM does not have this version available.``/usr/local/src/php5434/php-5.4.34/sapi/cli/php: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
make: *** [ext/phar/phar.php] Error 127
```

These are the current ICU versions and locations in the server; I beleive libicui18n.so.36 at /usr/lib64 is the one recognized by the server and the rest are being ignored:`

```
/usr/lib/libicui18n.so
/usr/lib/libicui18n.so.36
/usr/lib/libicui18n.so.36.0
/usr/lib64/libicui18n.so
/usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.36
/usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.36.0
/usr/lib64/sw/libicui18n.so.51
/usr/lib64/sw/libicui18n.so.51.2
/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so
/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so.48
/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so.48.0
/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so.48.1.1
/usr/local/php5434-cgi/lib/libicui18n.so`
```

How can I make this install either use    /usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so.48 or install it at     /usr/lib64`

TIA